# comparing Python code for equivalence

Tags: python

Is there a reliable, automatic way (such as a command-line utility) to check if two Python files are **equivalent** modulo whitespace, semicolons, backslash continuations, comments, etc.? In other words, that they are identical to the interpreter?

For example, this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('foo\n')
sys.stdout.write('bar\n')
```

should be considered equivalent to this:

```
import   sys
sys.stdout.\
    write('foo\n'); sys.stdout.\
    write(

    'bar\n') # This is an unnecessary comment
```

Comment: The second one makes me feel ill... :)

Comment: [stupid guess] compare the pyc files?

Comment: @LevLevitsky -- I doubt that will work since python needs to store line numbers for printing in tracebacks.

Comment: I don't see how those are `identical`, the output may be the same but how do you know they're interpreted the same?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module.

Example (for Python 2):

```
import ast

x = r'''import sys
sys.stdout.write('foo\n')
sys.stdout.write('bar\n')'''

y = r'''import   sys
sys.stdout.\
    write('foo\n'); sys.stdout.\
    write(

    'bar\n') # This is an unnecessary comment'''

xd = ast.dump(ast.parse(x))
yd = ast.dump(ast.parse(y))
print xd == yd
```

You can of course read in the source code from actual files instead of string literals.

*Edit:*

So that the comments make sense, I'd like to note that I originally proposed using the built-in [`compile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile) function.  However, @Jian found a simple case that it didn't handle well.  Perhaps it could be adapted, as suggested by @DSM, but then the solution becomes a little less tidy.  Maybe not unreasonably so, but if the `ast` parse-and-dump works as well or better, it's the more straightforward way.

Comment: That seems to give the wrong result (not equivalent) for values `x = "foo = 3"` and `y = "foo = \\\n3"`

Comment: @Jian: try `for k in dir(xc): print k, getattr(xc,k) == getattr(yc, k)`.  It looks like the two compile objects are only differing in `co_firstlineno`, which makes sense, under the circumstances.

Comment: @DSM: I think Jian has a fair point. He is looking for a way to check equivalence, and his `foo = 3` example does seem like it ought to test `True`. I specifically mentioned `compile()` because it's simple and built-in, but perhaps hayden's suggestion (the `parser` module) is more reliable.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried @hayden's approach on the original example (posted in the question), and it gives `False` (though it gives `True` for the `foo = 3` example in these comments).

Comment: @JohnY: I meant that it's possible that making a dict of everything but the `co_firstlineno` would work as a definition of equivalence.  Probably there's some other corner case, but nothing which involves `co_firstlineno` is going to match when, well, the lines are different.

Comment: @JohnY: I'd like to accept the part of your answer that uses `ast`. Before I do that, would you mind writing it out as a separate answer, or deleting the `compile` section from this answer? That way, it will be less confusing for someone who comes upon this answer for the first time.

Comment: @Jian: I agree it was confusing. I've rewritten it so that `ast` is front and center. I left a note about `compile()` at the end because I prefer not to make people wade through the edit logs to make sense of the comments.

Answer (score 6):

Use python's [parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html):

```
In [1]: import parser

In [2]: with open('file1.py', 'r') as f1:
    st1 = parser.suite(f1.read())

In [3]: with open('file2.py', 'r') as f2:
    st2 = parser.suite(f2.read())

In [4]: st1.compile() == st2.compile()
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: What version of Python?  This gives `False` for me (64-bit Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7).

Comment: @JohnY I updated this so it should work now! *The example files I was testing against weren't a very good (i.e. not those from the OP)...*

Comment: @JohnY Confusingly (in the `foo = 3` example) it seems `st1==st2` does not imply `st1.compile() == st2.compile()`... so my answer seems incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Python includes its own parser. Apply it to both files, then check that the result is structurally equivalent.